# How do I use the field OWS_ParentID to filter a view?

Tags: task-list

I have a task list and want to make a view that only shows items where ows_ParentID is empty.

I have access to SPD and am willing to make a workflow if needed but I can't locate this field anywhere.

Question:
How do I use the field OWS_ParentID to filter a view?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to be able to do this through the web UI but I found a reasonable compromise for a non-admin.

In SPD I opened the view and used this for the query:

```
<Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name="ParentID" /></IsNull></Where></Query>
```